# Как проверить находится ли строка внутри списка предопределенных строк?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oпределил список строк, который содержит различные коды стран. Например:

> USA,CHINA,HK,JPN и т.д.

Как я могу проверить, является ли входная переменная кодом страны в списке?

Использую следующий код для проверки, но результат неверный:

```
declare
    country_list  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(200) := 'USA,CHINA,HK,JPN';
    input VARCHAR2(200);
begin
    input := 'JPN';
    if input IN (country_list) then
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('It is Inside');
    else       
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('It is not Inside');
    end if;
end;
/
```

> It is not Inside

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to test if a string is inside a list of predefined strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2742174) от участника [@drupalspring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316254/drupalspring)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/2742174

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно еще воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
declare
    type tokenList is table of varchar2 (8);  
    countrylist constant varchar2 () := 'USA,CHINA,HK,JPN';
    input varchar2 (8) := 'JPN';
begin
    if (REGEXP_INSTR (countrylist, '(^|\W)'||input||'(\W|$)') >0) then
         dbms_output.put_line ('It is Inside');
    else       
         dbms_output.put_line ('It is not  Inside');
    end if;
end;
/
```

> It is Inside

PS к сожалению Oracle не поддерживает расширенные спец. символы - такие как `'\b'` (`word boundary`), поэтому приходится использовать более длинные регулярные выражения.

Comment: Можно конечно, на англ. SO такой варинт никто не предложил.

Comment: Перевёл согласно метке на PL/SQL. Ничего?

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо! :)

Answer (score 3):

Операрор `IN` ожидает список строк, а не строку в виде списка.

Самое простое решение, определить список как коллекцию, и проверять, если строка в этой коллекции:

```
declare
    type tokenList is table of varchar2 (8);  
    countrylist constant tokenList := tokenList ('USA','CHINA','HK','JPN');
    input varchar2 (8) := 'JPN';
begin
    if (input member of countrylist) then
         dbms_output.put_line ('It is Inside');
    else       
         dbms_output.put_line ('It is not  Inside');
    end if;
end;
/
```

> It is Inside

---